# Mule ESB annotation doesn't work

Tags: annotations, mule, schedule

I try to use @Schedule Annotation in mule esb, but it does not work. I don't know what's wrong  with it. My java code :

```
public class MyCache {

    @Schedule(interval=1000)
    public void writeStr(){

        Log.debug("111112222222223333333334444444444");
        System.out.println("111112222222223333333334444444444");
    }

}
```

Comment: Mule version? Also: how do you configure this in XML?

Comment: David, my mule version is v3.4. Does it need to be configured in the xml file? But I haven't seen any xml configuration about annotation in the mule-esb-user-guide. It only shows the annotation in the java code.

Comment: You need to declare MyCache to be able to use it, whether as a Mule component or a Spring Bean. Otherwise this class will never be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reason that goes beyond imagination, you have to use `@Schedule` annotated Java components in the obsolete model/service container for it to work.

Your above class (that I put in the `com.acme` package) works with the following on Mule 3.4.0:

```
<model>
    <service name="myCacheScheduler">
        <component>
            <singleton-object class="com.acme.MyCache" />
        </component>
    </service>
</model>
```

Comment: Thx, David. Now it runs well.