# Mule spring bean schedule run

Tags: mule

We have defined spring beans in Mule-config.xml. Certain public methods in this bean class needs to be periodically executed. We attempted to used spring quartz and spring task scheduler (adding beans in mule-config.xml)- but method is not executing in a schedule way  - it is not triggered. Even using annotation (scheduled) does not work. Any work around for this? Any issue with spring scheduler with mule? Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `Schedule` annotation, take a look at this [recent answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17889535/387927) for a workaround.

Otherwise, Spring Quartz should work fine too. What have you tried? Share your config and specify the Mule version you're using. I'll review my answer accordingly.