# Mule @Schedule annotation not working in Mavenized project

Tags: maven, annotations, mule, schedule

I am working on a project which is a mavenized web application having Mule support in it. I need to implement Scheduling for which i tried @Schedule annotation in a dummy application with the help of this question that was posted before
[Mule ESB annotation doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854025/mule-esb-annotation-doesnt-work).
It was working fine in dummy project but its not working in my web application. I've tried using Model- Service component and also tried to implement it by creating the Bean of the class so it can be loaded on startup, but all in vain.
I'm using Mule version 3.6.0
The code I used for Model Service is:

```
<model>
<service name="Scheduler">
    <component>
        <singleton-object class="com.dummy.package.TestBean" />
    </component>
</service>
```

And the Java code for the same is:

```
 public class TestBean 
{
    @Schedule(interval = 1000)
    public void printSomething() 
    {
        System.out.println("Printed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "dummy application"? How different is it from the web application? Is Mule starting at all in your web-app? Also `model` and `service` have been obsolete since Mule 3.0.0, do not use them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I meant by dummy app was that it was a mule project created in Anypoint with the model-service component placed in the config.xml (was creating a POC on @Schedule in Mule) and a TestBean class. When I started up the server, it automatically started the Scheduler and was printing every second. But, when I tried the same thing in a mavenised web-project of mine(an integration project of my company using Mule,Spring,Hibernates having various flows and connectors), it wasn't executing the scheduler. I've placed all dependencies in the pom.xml but Scheduler never runs.

Comment: And, if the model-service have been made obsolete, how can I use @Schedule and set scheduling on java methods?

Comment: Since this service was basically doing nothing except wrapping a bean and not exposing it, I suggest you use Spring scheduling instead http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support

Comment: In any case, if something works in Studio it should work in a web-app. Did you wire things properly so Mule gets started? Check my example here: https://github.com/ddossot/mule-webapp-example

Comment: Thank you David, but i used quartz connector instead of annotation. Anyways thanks a lot for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spring's `@Scheduled` annotation instead and load the bean with:

```
<spring:beans>
  <spring:bean name="testBean" class="com.dummy.package.TestBean" />
<spring:beans>
```

Indeed, the `service` you currently have does nothing with the bean: it just loads it but does not wire it to an endpoint. So you gain nothing from Mule there.

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support